# Python Function number doesn't affect how many times it runs?

Tags: python, function

If I write:

```
def f(n):
    blah
f(x)
```

Then as long as 'x' is a number, f will run exactly once. e.g. I just tried:

```
def f(n):
    c = 1
    print c
f(x)
```

With 'x' as 0 and then 10, and the output was '1' both times. What does the number 'x' actually represent, and how do I get the function to run 'x' number of times?

I've solved my problem now with a workaround (I was going to post this question earlier but apparently I'm restricted to posting every 90 minutes) but I'd still like to know for future.

My program looked similar to this:

```
def f(n):
    m = 0
    c = blah
    if condition(c):
        m = 1
    d = line involving c that had to be run before the end of the function loop, but after the if statement
    f(m)
f(1)
```

But the output kept looping because even though m = 0, f(0) still caused the function to loop. My workaround was:

```
m = 0

def f(n):
    global m
    m = 0
    c = blah
    if condition(c):
        m = 1
    else:
        m = 0
    d = line involving c that had to be run before the end of the function loop, but after the if statement
    if m = 1:
        f(1)
f(1)
```

Which worked fine (and actually, looking back at it, I don't think 'd' did need to be run after the if statement, so I could've just done if condition(c): f(1)), but it seemed redundant. I'm not sure why I have to specify a number for f(n), but if I leave it blank or input a string it fails to run. Is there a less 'clumsy' fix to this?

(I'm really new to programming, so please explain in fairly simple terms..!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to run a number of times, you just need to code up a loop of some description. For a known-in-advance quantity, you can use `for`:

```
def f(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print i+1, "Pax is awesome"
    print

x = 3
f(x)
f(x-1)
f(7)
```

Running that code will give you:

```
1 Pax is awesome
2 Pax is awesome
3 Pax is awesome

1 Pax is awesome
2 Pax is awesome

1 Pax is awesome
2 Pax is awesome
3 Pax is awesome
4 Pax is awesome
5 Pax is awesome
6 Pax is awesome
7 Pax is awesome
```

---

If you want to loop until a *general* condition is met (rather than a fixed number of times), you can use `while` rather than `for`:

```
def f(n):
    while (n % 8) != 0:
        print n, "Pax is awesome"
        n += 1
f(3)
```

This loop will continue running until `n` reaches a multiple of eight:

```
3 Pax is awesome
4 Pax is awesome
5 Pax is awesome
6 Pax is awesome
7 Pax is awesome
```

---

Your workarounds seem a little strained, especially in the sense that they use wholly unnecessary recursion.

You should aim for *clarity* of code as your primary goal (I call this optimising for readability). Doing so will make your code less likely to contain bugs, and easier to maintain down the track.

Comment: Oh, okay, so if I put for i in range (n): ... if: n +=1 or something - that would work? Although I guess since it only reads 'for i in range (n)' at the start of the function, the if command won't change anything and the function would still run only once.

Comment: Also, I'm still not sure why the function needs a parameter in the first place, since you could just write "for i in range (x)" instead...? I guess it's just easier to write it like that for when you call the function?

Comment: @Patrik, you don't need to _change_ `i`, the `for-range` loop does that for you. And, in terms of the parameter, that's just good coding habits. You may want to call the function from somewhere else, using `y` or `42`. I'll modify the example to show both these features.

Comment: But in my program, I wanted the number of times the function ran to be dependent on an if statement within that function - so if I used "for i in range(n)" I know I wouldn't need to change 'i', but I would need to increase 'n' if I wanted the function to loop an additional time.

Comment: @Patrik, if you don't know the iteration count in advance, `for` is probably not what you want. I've added to the answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand... maybe? [Here](http://ideone.com/xT9DWy) is the program I made - 'cf' was the function I was having trouble with. You don't have to (obviously), but if you want, I'd really appreciate some critique on the program. (Don't bother with reading the block of comments I made at the end, though, even if you do decide to look at it...)